# Dans le mois de la réception de l’avis

Tags: expressions, prépositions

> Ou encore, l’avis peut omettre de préciser que le locataire a un **mois**
> pour signifier par écrit qu’il n’est pas d’accord avec l’augmentation.
>
> Peu importe le cas, le locataire qui désire contester la hausse de
> loyer devrait quand même envoyer, **dans** le **mois** de la réception de
> l’avis, une lettre au propriétaire pour lui dire qu’il refuse la
> hausse proposée.

([lien](https://educaloi.qc.ca/capsules/le-renouvellement-de-bail-et-la-hausse-de-loyer/))

En raison de la première phrase, je comprends *dans le mois de la réception de l’avis* comme *j'ai reçu l'avis le 23 février et je peux répondre au propriétaire d'ici trente jours*. Sinon je l'airais compris comme *je dois envoyer ma réponse ce mois ; le premier mars, ce sera trop tard*.

Quelle est la signification exacte du ***dans** le **mois** de la réception de l’avis* ?

Comment: Further down in the link it says: Que puis-je répondre à la proposition de modification des conditions du bail? **Dans le mois qui suit la réception de l’avis de modification du locateur**, vous pouvez lire : That is clear; the other is not clear that it means you have 30 days.

Comment: The French says one thing, the English another (including a mistake) and Québec jurisprudence another. I believe the jurisprudence establishes that this means: dans le mois qui suit la récéption de l'avis even though the law does not say it that way.

Comment: @LétaleD'incivilisation La loi dit que le locataire a 30 jours pour réagir et exprimer son avis par écrit. S'il ne le fait pas, il est sous-entendu qu'il ait accepté l'augmentation. (J'espère qu'après _sous-entendu que_ on emploi le subjonctif. Je ne me rappelle plus où j'avais lu cette information, mais j'en suis sûre.

Comment: @LétaleD'incivilisation Merci. Oui, si l'immeuble a été construit depuis moins de 5 ans, il est impossible de refuser l'augmentation, le proprio peut faire ce qu'il veut, il y a beaucoup d'articles sur ce sujet dans des journeaux maintenant. Mais le locataire peut quitter l'immeuble s'il ne veut pas payer. Sauf qu'il y a peu de logements libres... // En tout cas, j'aurais dû lire ce texte aussi en anglais, je comprends beaucoup mieux _within_, je n'étais pas du tout sûre que j'aie bien compris _**dans** le mois de la réception_.

Comment: S'il est  huit heures moins cinq,  ***je pars dans l'heure*** ne signifie pas *je pars avant qu'il soit huit heures* mais *je pars rapidement et je serai certainement parti à huit heures cinquante-cinq*. C'est sensiblement ce même *dans* que l'on retrouve dans *envoyer une lettre dans le mois de la réception de l'avis*.

Comment: @LétaleD'incivilisation Je trouve dommage que tu aies retiré tes commentaires et, avant, ta réponse. Heureusement, j'ai lu tes commentaires, mais pas ta réponse, j'ai juste vu que tu l'avais écrite. Et il me semble que tu as changé de nom, je ne le vois plus en haut lorsque je tape _@Lé_. Perso, tes réponses sont utiles.

Comment: @LétaleD'incivilisation Non, je l'ai vue ce matin, mais je ne l'ai pas lue alors. Puis, quand je suis revenue, elle n'était plus là. Ok, je vois, une nouvelle discussion interminable... Si tu veux, je vais la lire, et tu pourrais l'effacer dans environ 15 minutes. Merci beaucoup :)

Comment: Oreste, "La loi dit que le locataire a 30 jours pour réagir et exprimer son avis par écrit." Oú ça? La loi dit: dans le mois de la réception de l’avis. Je vais vous dire quelque chose. J'ai téléphone à l"Office québecois qui est responsable de ces textes de loi. Le jeune homme était aussi surpris que moi de la traduction vers l'anglais. Et il a dit que le français n'était pas clair. Il a pris note des mes remarques et m'a dit qu'on va revenir vers moi. Alors, je vous tient au courant.

Comment: Je lui ai demandé également s'il pourrait me dire si les 30  jours c'est dans la jurisprudence québecoise en la matière.

Comment: L'OQLF n'a aucune responsabilité par rapport à ces textes. Le Code civil est une loi du Québec et elle a été votée par l'Assemblée nationale du Québec. Le Code civil a été refondu en 1994.  L'ignorance d'un préposé ne te donne pas raison. Rien ne va changer, ce préposé n'a aucun pouvoir de rien faire et la loi était et reste claire et personne sauf toi n'a besoin d'une confirmation de quoi que ce soit. Tu n'es simplement pas familière avec cette manière de s'exprimer. @Lambie

Comment: @LétaleD'incivilisation Il se peut tout simplement que ce préposé soit allophone, et, comme moi, il a commencé à se poser des questions.

Comment: @Oreste Tout à fait possible, même probable parce que je ne connais personne dans mon coin qui serait supris par cette formulation. Ça m'inquiète que la fréquentation ou la participation limitée des francophones finisse par laisser place à une incertitude basée sur un manque de familiarité avec la langue. Parfois le régionalisme complique les choses en plus.

Answer (score 2):

C'est un site québécois mais ce sont les termes au [*Code civil*](https://www.legisquebec.gouv.qc.ca/fr/version/lc/CCQ-1991?code=se:1945) du Québec. Ça [signifie](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/dans) assurément *d'ici un mois* où un [*mois*](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/mois) réfère à 30 jours ; le délai est créé par référence au moment ultérieur avec comme point de départ le moment de la réception de l'avis. Ou si on veut le voir comme « à l'intérieur » d'un délai de 30 jours, pourquoi pas. Donc [*avant*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%E2%80%99ici#Locution_pr%C3%A9positive) 30 jours à partir de l'avis. Je pense que j'aurais employé « dans le même mois de la réception de l'avis » ou « au cours du mois où l'avis est reçu » si j'avais voulu dire peu importe quel jour d'un mois, avant la fin de ce mois-là (*février* par ex.).<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> On a accès à de l'[information](https://www.canlii.org/fr/#search/origin1=/fr/qc/legis/lois/rlrq-c-ccq-1991/derniere/rlrq-c-ccq-1991.html&linkedNoteup=&section1=1945) sur l'[interprétation](https://www.legisquebec.gouv.qc.ca/fr/document/lc/I-16), dont les canons (41, 41.1 par ex.), incluant celui du [sens courant](https://decisions.scc-csc.ca/scc-csc/scc-csc/fr/item/5783/index.do) des mots quand ils ne sont pas définis dans la loi à tout le moins, et l'objectif de la disposition ainsi que le libellé des autres articles de la section du Code, interdiraient possiblement une interprétation qui ferait en sorte de faire varier la capacité du locataire de faire valoir son refus, donc ses droits, selon le moment du mois où il reçoit l'avis — il me semble.</sub>

Comment: La [version anglaise](https://educaloi.qc.ca/en/capsules/renewing-a-residential-lease-and-rent-increases/) est claire: *Whatever the notice looks like, a tenant who wants to refuse the rent increase should send a letter to the landlord saying so, within one month of receiving the landlord’s notice.* J'ai découvert *locateur*, on dit *bailleur* par chez nous.

Comment: The English version is a translation from the French. The French actually says within ***the*** month of receipt**, not within one month. dans le mois de la récéption, cad, au cours du mois de la réception. within one month would means they have 30 days more. The French says they have until the month "en cours" ends. In Québec, it's the French that counts. And there are often issues with translation into English of legal texts there.

Comment: Donc avant 30 jours à partir de l'avis: C'est ça. Exactement.

Comment: @Lambie La phrase en français est ambigüe mais son interprétation restrictive (avant la fin du mois courant) ne tiendrait pas devant un tribunal. *Dans le mois de la réception de l'avis* signifie ici *à l'intérieur de la période d'un mois qui contient cette date* et il est évident que la réponse ne pouvant pas être antérieure à la réception de la lettre, cette période débute à ce moment-là, pas avant. Si ce n'était pas le cas, les locateurs/bailleurs enverraient tous leur augmentations le 28 ou le 29 du mois pour mettre les locataires devant le fait accompli. Ce serait injuste et absurde.

Comment: I can see how problematic this is: dans le mois de la réception de l’avis, is not: dans le mois qui suit la récéption de l'avis.  Which would be that they have 30 days.

Comment: 1 mois à compter de la réception de l’avis du locateur-propriétaire. https://www.infopreneur.quebec/2019/12/12/dossier-special-sur-la-reprise-de-logement/ **That is what is meant** but that is not what: dans le mois de la réception de l'avis means. Fyi, dans le mois cannot mean within a month. Sorry. Here: it is clear: Que puis-je répondre à la proposition de modification des conditions du bail?
Dans le mois qui suit la réception de l’avis de modification du locateur, vous pouvez soit : That is in the **same link** given by Oreste.

Comment: dans le mois de la réception de l'avis says: IN the month the notice is received. Even Oreste's link states: Que puis-je répondre à la proposition de modification des conditions du bail?
**Dans le mois qui suit la réception de l’avis de modification du locateur, vous pouvez soit** : There are your 30 days and there is the meaning though not the letter of the law.

Comment: Merci, j'ai tout recopié dans mon fichier ! :)

Comment: Une réponse davantage ancrée uniquement dans la langue serait plus utile pour l'apprenant. Le justiciable dispose de différentes sources d'information, dont _éducaloi_. Je suis d'accord que _dans le mois qui suit la réception de l’avis_ ne suscite pas la discussion, contrairement à ce qu'on présente. On peut trouver la formulation du Code moins précise ou plus régionale. Je ne sais pas ce qui en est.

Comment: Trouvé dans le [code de l'urbanisme français](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/codes/section_lc/LEGITEXT000006074075/LEGISCTA000006175925/) : ***Dans le mois de la réception de la demande**, le maire la transmet avec son avis au directeur départemental de l'équipement. Cet avis doit être motivé et communiqué au préfet par le maire s'il est défavorable. Il est réputé favorable s'il n'est pas intervenu **dans le délai d'un mois prévu ci-dessus**. Le préfet, **dans les quinze jours de la réception de la demande** par le directeur départemental de l'équipement, fait connaître...*

Comment: Document de la Cour Supérieure, Province de Québec, District de Montréal: 2.29 Suivant les règles établies en matière de logement au Québec, un locataire peut
refuser une augmentation de loyer en avisant la locatrice de son refus, **dans un
délai d’un mois de la réception de l’avis de modification de bail**, conformément à
l’article 1945 du Code civil du Québec; https://www.registredesactionscollectives.quebec/en/Fichier/Document?NomFichier=2099.pdf Lá oui, c'est un mois à partir de la réception, comme dit la Cour. Comme je disais, c'est la jurisprudence qui compte.

Comment: Beyond the idiomatic phrasing of the Code and its natural meaning, this is civil law, not common law, so we don't need case law to figure out trvial words and phrases from typical French language. Furthermore everything you said goes against canons of statutory interpretation. You don't analyze the language in a vacuum; the English language version confirms the meaning, your interrpretation would lead to unfair treatment, a strict construction could lead to an understanding that there is a fixed month for everyone to receive the notice etc. The text has been there since 1994.

Comment: @LétaleD'incivilisation Not everyone would agree with you re:  "the English language version confirms the meaning." You do realize that some translations into English of Quebec laws are faulty? In civil law, jurisprudence **interprets** the law; in common law, jurisprudence can **make a law**. About the issues re translation found in the Montreal Gazette (which backs up what I said at the beginning here), here is an opinion piece: https://montrealgazette.com/opinion/opinion-english-versions-of-quebec-laws-all-too-often-fall-short

Comment: @Lambie Thanks, that article is interesting, but it has no bearing. Is "within one month after receiving the notice" not correct English? It is correct. Even if the English language version was not grammatical, it could still help if its meaning was clear. That being said you don't need to remind me of the basics of _stare decisis_ and such, in case you still don't understand this, I was trained in the field. More than once.

Comment: @LétaleD'incivilisation The translation from the French is incorrect as I pointed out at the beginning of this thread. The French is fine French, the English is fine English. But the translation is wrong. You gave me a lecture about civil law versus common law and I really do not need that and wanted to show I know about legal translation and civil law and common law regimes. OK? All these subtle and not so subtle digs are really tiresome. I never push back by making quasi-nasty comments.

Comment: Voyons donc... Il faut se comporter d'une manière bienveillante et, si possible, logique. Personne ne rédigera alors "quasi-nasty comments".

Comment: Correction: I never push back and make quasi-personal comments (I am referring to me) **but this time I did**.

Comment: @Lambie So you know some and I know some, now that we're done measuring that, no, the translation is accurate. In the phrasing _est tenu, dans le mois de la réception de l’avis de modification du bail, d’aviser le locateur de son refus_, French can leverage _dans_ here to mean _within_, and so it does in this instance. The fact you can have a clearer or less ambiguous phrasing does not imply this phrasing doesn't mean what it does mean, nor that it needs to rely on case law. Instances have been found in French law too. I produced a dictionary entry showing _dans_ can be used as _d'ici_.

Comment: @Lambie I've explained this in my answer but you must also not neglect the fact that _mois_ can mean 30 days and that this phrasing would not imho be typical to express the current month, which I've also explained in my answer above. For all these reasons, each on its own being sufficient to establish this usage and construction, I conclude that the statement that _dans_ has to mean the current month in the Code, and therefore the conclusion that within is not adequate, to be false. The English language version of the Code may be poor in some instances but not here so that's a distraction.

Comment: @Lambie You can repeat as many times as you want that the translation is wrong and I'll tell you as many times as you do that it is right. Translation wasn't even the question in OP's! What's important here is to understand that such a construction might feel less intuitive than something else, but nevertheless this usage is possible, as evidenced by the very question and the meaning of the words in the Code, on the éducaloi website, and in French law.